# Does $\chi_{A_\epsilon} \to \chi_{\{x : f(x) = 0\}}$ if $A_\epsilon = \{ x \in \Omega : 0 \leq f(x) < \epsilon\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Define $A_\epsilon = \{ x \in \Omega : 0 \leq f(x) < \epsilon\}$ where $f$ is a given function say in $L^1(\Omega)$.

Is it true that $$\chi_{A_\epsilon} \to \chi_{\{x : f(x) = 0\}}$$ pointwise?

How do I prove this rigorously? Is it correct: fix $x_0$, then if $f(x_0) > 0$, then whenever $\epsilon < f(x_0)$ then $\chi_{A_\epsilon}(x_0) = 0$ for all such $\epsilon$. OTOH if $f(x_0)=0$, then $\chi_{A_\epsilon}(x_0)=1$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yeah, your proof is correct.